# How to map 2D coordinates to a unique colour (i.e. 2D colormap)?

Tags: color, visualization

Colourmaps in Mathematica usually map a single value with a colour.
Are there 2-dimensional colourmaps available where one can map 2d coordinates to a unique colour? (i.e. in a way that coordinates that are close to each other also have a similar colour)

Alternatively, I was thinking of importing images of existing 2d colourmaps (e.g. from here: https://github.com/dominikjaeckle/Color2D) and reading pixel values at the transformed positions.

Maybe there are better ideas around?

Comment: Have you seen `Hue`?

Comment: Ah, thats an idea!

Comment: And of course, things like `Function[{x, y}, RGBColor[{x, 0, y}]]` also work (for `x` and `y` between `0` and `1`. You can also construct color functions with `Blend`. But I agree that a couple of nice 2D- and 3D-color schemes would not harm. =)